# Diferencia entre ¿async y async*? y entre ¿yield y yield*? en Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

Estudiando y tratando de aprender el patrón bloc en Flutter me he topado con estos términos en el método mapEventToState, reconozco el async y su función.

Pero no encuentro porqué hay casos en que llevan ese asterisco y que lo diferencia del async sin él.

El yield pasa lo mismo eh visto que en algunas ocasiones lo ponen sin el (ejemplo de patron bloc https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-bloc-package-295b53e95c5c) y en otras si lo ponen (ejemplo de login firebase - flutter con patron bloc https://medium.com/flutter-community/firebase-login-with-flutter-bloc-47455e6047b0).

La pregunta es ¿que los diferencia?

Answer (score 3):

**async**

Utilizar `async` en una función te permite `await` (esperar) al realizar un trabajo, el cual finalizara en algún momento en el futuro.

```
Future<String>  crearOrdenMensaje() async {
  var orden = await buscarOrdenUsuario();
  return 'Your order is: $orden';
}

Future<String>  buscarOrdenUsuario() =>
    // Imagina que esto es un poco mas complejo y lento
    Future.delayed(
      Duration(seconds: 2),
      () => 'Cafe Dominicano',
    );

Future<void>  main() async {
  print('Buscando la orden...');
  print(await crearOrdenMensaje());
}
```

***async**

Lo utilizas cuando esperas un grupo de acciones en el futuro. Piénsalo como el `Future` de mas de un `Future`, por eso la función es de tipo `Stream`.

```
Stream<int> numerosAsincronicos(int n) async* {
  int k = 0;
  while (k < n) yield k++;
}
```

**yield**

Emite los valores de un `Stream`, si te lo preguntas no se utiliza `return`, por que este termina con la ejecución de la función, y retorna al que ejecuto la misma.

**yield***

Cuando se termina de generar valores (`yield`), `yield*` generara sus propios valores.

```
import 'dart:async';

main() async {
  await for (int i in numerosDesde(5)) {
    print('$I botellas de cerveza');
  }
}

Stream numerosDesde(int n) async* {
  if (n >= 0) {
    await new Future.delayed(new Duration(milliseconds: 100));
    yield n;
    yield* numerosDesde(n - 1);
  }
}
```

Resultado

```
$ dart yield_each.dart
5 botellas de cerveza
4 botellas de cerveza
3 botellas de cerveza
2 botellas de cerveza
1 botellas de cerveza
0 botellas de cerveza
```

Fuentes:

[Working with futures: async and await](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await#working-with-futures-async-and-await)

[async](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await)

[synchronous](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#generators)

[yield*](http://jpryan.me/dartbyexample/examples/yield_star/)

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu explicación y por las fuentes